# sending http post request in c with wininet.h

Tags: c, http, winhttp

i want to send a http post request in c with the wininet.h library.

But i dont know how to do this.
I only find c++ tutorials everywhere but none for c.
Can someone show me how to do this?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry, what's the wininet.h library? Have you some url where it can be found? can you edit your post to include some reference of that library?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read ["Unix network Programming" Vol 1 (Richard Stevens et al)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_Network_Programming)  It shows you how to use C for networking purposes.  Also reading the [HTTP protocol specifications](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616), which describes how to connect to a web server and how a POST method is composed and handled.  You don't post any code, so it's very difficult to help you from here, leaving us only to direct you to a good source of information (the ones cited here are)